# how to set default selection on bottom Navigation bar android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

[I want to make this middle item as default selection when I open My application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hCDJw.jpg)

Comment: Can you post the code where you initialize your bottom navigation bar?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

write the code in onCreate method. remember dont write in mBottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener{}

```
    BottomNavigationView mBottomNavigationView=(BottomNavigationView)findViewById(R.id.bottom_nav);
mBottomNavigationView.getMenu().findItem(R.id.item_id).setChecked(true);
```